# Can’t get this light cover off & no brand name on it

Tags: lighting

This fan was in the house we bought. No label so we don’t know the maker. Bulb burned out but try as we might we can’t get the globe off. Looks like halogen bulb if that helps. Had a remote but it never worked. Can’t find it to see if there is a maker listed. No idea where this was purchased. We are in Florida

[image]

Comment: Have you tried twisting the lens off? Is there a decorative bezel you could pry off to expose fasteners?

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Stack Exchange. There's a lot to be learned by seeing just how the lens is loose. Pulling on different edges, twisting in different directions, etc., all may suggest the answer.